# send array as parameter to route users.destroy

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I want to use method `destroy` to delete one or more users, so it suppose to recieve an array and then delete whatever values given:

```
    public function destroy(Request $request)
    {
            // DB::table('users')->whereIn('id', $request->user)->delete();
            
            dd(var_dump($request->user));
    }
```

However, the method recieves it as string, which is the first `id` passed, and does not recieve other values, how can i make it recieve the array as is ? thanks in advance

```
const deleteSelectedUsers = () => {
    const ids = [];
    selectedUsers.value.forEach((val) => {
        ids.push(val.id);
    });
    router.delete(route("users.destroy", ids));
    deleteUsers.value = false;
    selectedUsers.value = null;
    toast.add({
        severity: "success",
        summary: "Successful",
        detail: "Users Deleted",
        life: 3000,
    });
};
```

Comment: in this case I would probably create an invokable controller and destroy all the models whereIn your list of IDs

Comment: I see no indication that your `destroy()` method is "suppose to receive an array" or any attempt to process the request as an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In accordance with best practices, a typical Laravel Controller encompasses CRUD methods that handle individual model operations. However, if your requirements deviate from the standard CRUD operations, it is advisable to relocate the corresponding code to a new Controller tailored to your needs.

For instance, consider a `UserController` containing methods like `index`, `show`, `edit`, `update`, and `destroy`, each serving specific functionalities. However, if the task involves deleting multiple users, it might be more fitting to segregate this code into a distinct controller and organize it accordingly.

## My recommendation is to use an Invokable Controller, following these steps:

### 1. Create Route:

```php
Route::delete('/users/delete-many', DeleteManyUsersController::class)->name('users.delete-many');
```

### 2. Develop the Invokable Controller:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class DeleteManyUsersController extends Controller
{
    public function __invoke(Request $request)
    {
        $ids = $request->input('ids');

        // Validate user IDs if necessary

        User::whereIn('id', $ids)->delete();

        return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Users deleted successfully');
    }
}
?>
```

### 3. Execute the API call using InertiaJs:

```js
async deleteSelectedUsers() {
    try {
        const ids = this.selectedUsers.map(user => user.id);

        // Send a DELETE request to the Laravel backend using Inertia
        await this.$inertia.delete(route('users.delete-many'), { ids });

        // Handle a successful response
        this.deleteUsers = false;
        this.selectedUsers = null;
        this.$toast.success('Users deleted successfully', { duration: 3000 });
    } catch (error) {
        // Handle any errors
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

By employing this approach, your code adheres to best practices and maintains a cleaner, more modular structure, ensuring seamless management of user-related operations.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this answer if it helps you

```
     deleteSelectedUsers() {
        const ids = this.selectedUsers.map(user => user.id);

        // Send a DELETE request to the Laravel backend using Inertia
        this.$inertia.delete(route('users.destroy'), { ids: ids })
            .then(() => {
                // Handle successful response
                this.deleteUsers = false;
                this.selectedUsers = null;
                this.$toast.success('Users deleted successfully', { duration: 3000 });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                // Handle error
                console.error(error);
            });
    },
```

and your controller function is this

```
 public function destroy(Request $request){
    $ids = $request->input('ids');

    // Perform your delete logic here using $ids
    // For example:
    User::whereIn('id', $ids)->delete();

    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Users deleted successfully');
}
```

Comment: the `destroy` method in a controller is - normally - used to destroy a single model. I would rename the method to something like: `destroyMany`

Comment: Yes you can rename but you should change the method name and route name

Your route should be
Route::delete('/users/{user}', [UserController::class, 'destroyMany'])->name('users.destroyMany');

you need to change the route name users.destroyMany
and function name  destroyMany